# Setting Launch Parameters In Java Class

Tags: java, class, arguments, launch

Is there a way to make it so you can set memory usage arguments **inside** a java class, not using eclipse or a java program compiler, just simple code that you can do inside a class using notepad or something.
If you don't know what I mean, Here's an example:

```
public class Example {
   public Example() {
     -Xmx("1024M");
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     new Example();
   }
}
```

Please help, thank you! 
Note: I don't want to make a cmd/batch file to run it with -Xmx!

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is, or that it would be beneficial.  They're JVM runtime options, and can't be dynamically adjusted while the program is running, to the best of my knowledge.  I'll look into it a bit though...

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson and Makoto, I think I'll have to use a bat file then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory cannot be changed at run-time (by the time the JRE gets to your code statement, the memory has been set & cannot be changed).  The only way to achieve a different memory size is to relaunch the app. using a `Process` specifying larger memory (then close the original app. that does not have enough).

Of course, better to simply specify the required memory in the launch process (BAT file, [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) etc.).