# Determine optimal Java runtime parameters before launch?

Tags: java, batch-file, memory, heap-memory

we're running a Java application for rendering ans displaying quite a number of images. To make this smooth, we's like to assign a fair amount of heap space, and would like to check if there's a 64 bit version available on the computer. We'd like to run the application on many different computers, so manually checking the available memory and the Runtime version by trial and error is quite a hassle.

Does anyone know of a method to determine the availably memory that can be reserved for heap space, and to determine the available JREs; so we could somehow pass these parameters on to the JRE when executing the jar?

I'm aware that this would require some sort of batch file, like discussed in this thread:
 [Setting Launch Parameters In Java Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936046/setting-launch-parameters-in-java-class)

Has anyone come across a running example for a Windows environment? My knowledge about Windows Batch-files is limited at best.

Regards, Marius

Comment: Instead of checking the available memory and reserve heap depending on that, I would consider checking if there is enough memory for the heap space you need.  The difference is important, since starting your app with a reduced heap space will make your app vulnerable to OutOfMemory errors

Comment: The JRE already has a rather good default and will size the heap according to the available physical memory. In Java 7 it's a quarter of total RAM, or 1 GB max.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's the server VM specifically though; one has to make sure to be using it.

Comment: @Gimby I tested this: `java -client -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version` and it said `-XX:MaxHeapSize=2147483648`. That's 2 GB, so actually I was wrong in the comment above: it's up to 2 GB (both server and client).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: weird because I could have sworn that what you said was true at least in Java 6 update 17/18 and up; perhaps things changed in Java 7 which slipped by us.

Comment: @Gimby Which part do you mean? As I recall, Java 6's default `-Xmx` was just 64 MB.

Comment: The dynamic heap was in fact introduced in java 6 update 18: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html

Comment: Our problem is that the application does render a lot of images in a very short time (it's a psychological test, we're using Processing as graphical framework), so the VM seems not to be able to increase heap size fast enough to accomodate for this. With the -Xms parameter, it works, but the best setting for this parameter ist determined by the system environment. Setting it to 1500M, for example, fails on older machines.

Answer (score 2):

to check if java is 64-bit:

```
java -version 2>&1|find /i "64-Bit" && echo YEP!||echo NOPE!
```

To get free memory :

```
wmic os get freephysicalmemory
```

or:

```
systeminfo | find "Physical Memory"
```

**EDIT**
Universal and fast way to get free memory:

```
mshta "javascript:close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory').ItemIndex(0).AvailableBytes));"|more
```

assign result to variable:

```
for  /f "usebackq" %%a in (`mshta ^"javascript^:close^(new ActiveXObject^(^'Scripting.FileSystemObject^'^).GetStandardStream^(1^).Write^(GetObject^(^'winmgmts:^'^).ExecQuery^(^'Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory^'^).ItemIndex^(0^).AvailableBytes^)^);^"^|more`) do set free_mem=%%a
```

Comment: The last one is quite slow to complete because it scans all Hotfixes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes bu `WMIC` is not available on Home/Basic/starter editions of windows.Now thinking of mshta+vbscript for universal solution.

Comment: Hi, would these methods return a value that can safely be assignd to the JVM? And physical memory, I wouldn't mind if the value (at least on systems with less RAM) would include available memory including swap file, while physical would be limited to fee RAM alone?

Comment: I've added a code that allows the free memory to be assigned to variable.

Comment: page file can be get in similar manner .Check here for the wql queries: http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/pagefiles/

Comment: Your script works great, thanks! Is there some way to limit to value, e.g., limit it to 4G or something like this? On my computer, I get a value of about 13G, which seems a bit much. As far as I've read, all DOS variables are strings, so a numeric comparison won't work I guess (at least I've tried, and it doesn't work).

Comment: you can compare numbers in batch but they are limited to 32b integers - http://ss64.com/nt/if.html .You can get the memory in megabytes  - just use `AvailableMBytes` instad of `AvailableBytes` to avoid ineger overflow.

Comment: Great, with AvailableMBytes and if %free_mem% geq 8000 (set free_mem=8000 ) it works pefect! Thanks!